# How to georeference this image?

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing

I need to georeference this .tiff. I see coordinate values ranging South-North 550000-554000 and West-East 10000-12000. Do I need to know the coordinate system to georeference the image
[image]?[image]

Comment: Northern or Southern Hemisphere?

Comment: I'm going to assume Northern since that's where I am given this assignment.

Comment: You don't have enough information to easily find it. 11-12k easting is very small. It's possible the first digit (hundred thousands) was dropped, but that's not helpful. Do you have other data? Any idea where it's supposed to be?

Comment: Can you download 'exiftool' here: https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Then drag and drop the .tiff onto the shortcut icon for exiftool and screenshot the output.

Comment: If you take into account that coordinates might be swapped, you get location somewhere in Minessota, USA (check with http://projfinder.com/).

Comment: @debo The only thing you did not mention is where did you get this map ?  Where is the place are you trying to georeference ? Just need more info

Comment: This map is from a university assignment. I emailed my professor, and he said these are not real-world coordinates. I asked how I could georeference something with no real-word coordinates, and he said use the coordinates on the scan as real-world coordinates.

Comment: @debo  yes like others said it lacks the information... Maybe if you can go back and screenshot the whole map ?

Comment: @PROBERT I did upload the whol map screenshot... the legend it cut off, but don't think we need that to georeference. I think I have figured it out though. I went to data frame properties and specified map units to "meters".  I then opened the georeferencing toolbar, and input control points. I clicked the corner, then moved my mouse and right clicked and selected "x,y". I put in the values given from the map. After putting all four corners in, I selected "update georeference".

Comment: @debo  that is good that you made your endeavor first...